# How to lock/protect tags of mp3 files from being edited?

Tags: mp3, tags

Is there a way to lock/protect the mp3 tags from being edited again after me?
I know that the "read-only" feature in the windows properties can do it. but anyone can right click and unchecked it so I need any another way.

Thanks e?

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you need this?

Comment: @slhck: I am in risk of going off-topic here, but this question applies to over 50% of posts on SU. Explaining _why_ you need to do something is essential to get a good answer on _how_ do you get it done.

Comment: I don't think WHY is important.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about restricting access to id-tags (and essentially write-access to files) on your PC or local network, then you can set permissions specifically for your user account and restrict everyone else to read-only. This can be done if your mp3 files are stored in NTFS file system (From OP, I assume we are talking about windows environment here). You can read some good info about NTFS permissions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.11.howitworksntfs.aspx)

If you want to protect id-tags of mp3 files in general. Like if you send those files elsewhere or share them on the net, then I have to disappoint you, this seems to be impossible. At least I haven't heard of such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. There is no file/system that can be changed in one way or the other without any form of DRM. MP3's do not have DRM and thus you can change it afterwards. There are some encoding into the audio itself options, but that is very limited supported. You could use that as a watermark to proof the MP3 was originally yours, but thats all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Download [ID3 Tag Editor](http://www.softsea.com/download.php?id=830671621). You could edit your files while you're at it. Once you open it up you choose the file and save the file. It will automatically lock the text.

Answer (score -1):

If the user can write a file, they can also change the tags within that file. If in your scenario the user has the possibility to uncheck the write protection on the file, then there really isn't anything you can do.

The only (horrible) workaround would be to wrap your files in a proprietary container and supply a proprietary software that can read the file, but that's really not what you should do if you plan to distribute something — your users will get annoyed by that.